# How do I get the content of a Panel variant to display on as Content?

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

I've made a module that you can add to a Panel Variant's Content section by clicking a region's gear icon and selecting 'add content'. This seems to work fine and I can view the module's output if I set the Selection Rules to a certain url.

However, I want to add this module to a Node (by this I mean the sort of content where you can select Basic Page, Blog Post, Article, etc). When I click 'Add Content' I don't see where I can add the module - there's no Regions with little gear icons, unlike panel variants. It just seems like a page with a text field.

Would anyone know how I can actually add my Module to a new Content/Node page?

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I figured this out:

- 'Content' is actually Nodes. Don't know why they arnt just called 'Nodes'.
- There area different types on Nodes, these are called Content Types. You can add fields to a Content Type. Don't know why they're not called 'Node Types'.
- You can use Panel Variants as a kind of template for a Node. You can set Selection Rules to tell it which Nodes to apply it's self to.
- Here, in the Panel Variant you can attach Pane Component (my module) to a region.